# Searchable in RTL

Tags: android, search, android-recyclerview, menu, right-to-left

I have implemented Search for recyclerview using the link mentioned bellow. I want it to align correctly for RTL but search looks same for both English and Arabic, is there a way I can set it.

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

In the manifest I have set

```
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

This is my searchable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:label="@string/app_name"
/>
```

menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="info.androidhive.recyclerviewsearch.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
```

I tried to add text direction to searchable but it is not an attribute.
I know I can do textDirection and LayoutDirection for RTL support but not sure for this searchable how can i get that

This is my image on Arabic language. Search icon and the cursor starts from left, but in Arabic it should start from right, how can i get it working?

Any suggestions would be very helpful, if it wont work using this way, any recommendations on other library I can use for RTL support please.

thanks
R

[image]